# What is the minimum memory requirement for RHEL 4?

Tags: redhat, memory, legacy, rhel4

I know RHEL 4 is ancient history now, but trying to find minimum memory requirements on the Redhat website is proving to be almost impossible (or I'm searching for the wrong thing).

Minimum CPU requirements would be useful information too.

I have a system with 512MB RAM and a 2.8GHz Pentium 4 which I'd like to install RHEL 4 onto. If that's possible :-)

Comment: Is there some reason why you aren't installing a new release?  A new release should run fine there too.  Just remember it is all about the applications.  The Linux kernel itself has a relatively small footprint.

Comment: This system is solely to support a legacy application on a temporary basis. It's probably easier to deploy the original OS rather than risk a more modern version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redhat 4.x and CentOS 4.x will install just fine in that RAM/CPU footprint.

Answer (score 3):

[LinuxQuestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-enterprise-47/minimum-hardware-requirements-for-rhel-4-newbie-303445/) has an answer:

> You don't want to have less than 256MB of RAM in your system if you want to run RHEL 4, especially with an X desktop. I also wouldn't go much slower than a 500mhz CPU, either.